# A Tribute to Psych

Tags: crosswords, word-square

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #43: Variety Crossword Grids](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7062)</sup>

---

The following is a 4x5 grid:

[image]

Within the grid, there are 13 words laid out in the following way:

[image]

The words may go forwards or backwards along the lines.  That is, two words that are parallel do not necessarily read in the same direction.  The following are the clues for the 13 words, in no particular order:

**Clues**

1. Desserts made from #10
2. Requests
3. Type of attack
4. Wild west marshal
5. Threat ender
6. Smallville character
7. Relaxes
8. Type of code
9. The first half of a fruit
10. The second half of a fruit
11. Swedish airline
12. Where you might find villains
13. Sticky substance related to #9

To prevent mirror image answers, the upper right square is an **S**.

By the way, the title of the puzzle is in reference to the TV show *Psych*, [which prominently featured pineapples](https://screenrant.com/psych-pineapple-gag-origin-true-story-explained/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solved pineapple(!) as follows:

> [image]

Red (across-ish) clues:

> 2. Requests = **ASKS**
>  4. Wild west marshal = **[EARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgil_Earp)** (reversed)
>  1. Desserts made from #10 = **PIES**
>  6. Smallville character = **[LANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Smallville_characters)**
>  5. Threat ender = **ELSE** ("*or else...*")

Blue (diagonal-ish) clues:

> 13. Sticky substance related to #9 = **SAP** (reversed)
>  9. The first half of a fruit = **PINE**(apple)
>  8. Type of code = **[AREA](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/area%20code)**
>  11. Swedish airline = **[SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_Airlines)**

Green (down-ish) clues:

> 10. The second half of a fruit = (pine)**APPLE**
>  12. Where you might find villains = **LAIRS** (reversed)
>  3. Type of attack = **SNEAK** ("sneak attack") (reversed)
>  7. Relaxes = **EASES** (reversed)